# Vue Receive Data from listening Event directly [Can I create an inline handler?]

Tags: vue.js

Is there a way to receive the value directly without creating a function or $on?
Something like that:

```
<my-custom-component @saved="data => variable = data"></my-custom-component>
```

Comment: You're creating a function in your example. And assuming `variable` is a data property, it should work.

Comment: See also [the `.sync` modifier](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier), which is what you're getting pretty close to.

Comment: You could also just do `@saved="variable = $event"`

Comment: Thx guys! .sync is nice thanks @RoyJ I forgot about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[That works.](https://jsfiddle.net/bbsimonbb/eyvdpLw4/8/)** What's the problem?

**code**

```
Vue.component('my-custom-component',{
  template : `<button @click='$emit("saved",{data : "hello cobber"})'>Click me !</button>`
})

vm = new Vue({
  el : '#vueRoot',
  data : { variable : null }
})
```

**markup**

```
<div id="vueRoot">
  <my-custom-component @saved="data => variable = data"></my-custom-component>{{variable}}
</div>
```